# how to avoid checking if a variable is set ? (php)

Tags: php, variables

I want to use a variable in an if statement but I don't know if it is set or not.

I currently do this

```
if (isset ($array['var']) && ($array['var']==5) ) ....
```

There has to be a more elegant way to do this. What's the best practice?

Comment: I'd recommend using `array_key_exists('var', $array)` instead of `isset()` when dealing with arrays.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The three answers so far are not what I was looking for. The solution should be with less code than mine.

If PHP doesnt have some syntactic way to make it more elegant that would be the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Is your issue with having to define your own function? Usually, you'd place these functions in a common include file that you include at the top of every PHP script. Then, the amount of code does become less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed one of the areas where PHP might want to add some syntactic sugar.
Currently, the only way to write this more concise or maybe more *elegant* if you will, is with a custom function:

```
function array_val($array, $key) {
    return array_key_exists($key, $array) ? $array[$key]: false;
}

if (array_val($array, 'var') == 5) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

You could even extend on this to make the second param also accept a path:

```
function array_val($array, $path) {
    if (is_array($path)) {
        $current = $array;
        foreach ($path as $p) {
             if (!is_array($current)) return false;
             if (array_key_exists($p, $current)) $current = $current[$p];
             else return false;
        }
        return $current;
    }
    return array_val($array, array($path));
}

$myArr = array(
    'key1' => array(
        'key2' => array(
            'key3' => 'myValue'
        )
    )
);
echo array_val($myArr, array('key1', 'key2', 'key3')); // will echo 'myValue'
```

Comment: This is definetely not a bad way to do it!

Comment: Thanks NDM. I marked the answer as correct for telling me there is no better way in PHP to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** use for example:

```
if (isset ($array['var'])) {
   if ($array['var']==5) {
      // Do something here
   }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same? Unless there are going to be more checks inside the `if (isset` bit

Comment: The way is the same, but it is better to read. i think..

Comment: But you will end up with an unnecessary `if` statement. If you want it to be better to read why not just put the `$array['var'] == 5` on a newline inside the same `if` statement.

Comment: you are right, but i think its not more inefficient. Its only a example not a finish "must do" answer.

Comment: @q0re - Of course it is more inefficient, because there is an extra `if` statement.

Comment: As David Gard said, it is slightly more inefficient. There are two branches instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

I create a function that returns a default value if the key is not set:

```
//Have to take the array by reference, or you will get a notice about undefined variables.
//Just be sure you don't modify $array in this function.
function arrayValueWithDefault(&$array, $key, $default) {
    if (!is_array($array) || !array_key_exists($key, $array))
        return $default;

    return $array[$key];
}
```

It's great for things like reading from `$_GET` and `$_POST`, but you can use it on any array:

```
$id = arrayValueWithDefault($_GET, 'id', 0);
$name = arrayValueWithDefault($_POST, 'name', "");

$array = array(
    'count' => 3,
    'items' => array(0, 1, 2)
);

//Yes, I realize that you could just use sizeof() on $items here.
$count = arrayValueWithDefault($array, 'count', 0);
$items = arrayValueWithDefault($array, 'items', array());

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $item = $items[$i]; 
    echo $item;
}
```

So, in your specific example, you could do:

```
$var = arrayValueWithDefault($array, 'val', 0);

if ($var == 5)
    //do something
```